# Param urls onBeforeRequest.addListener has many url patterns cause loading page is so slow

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension. I used chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener to block some websites. But when the URLs param is so huge, the loading page experience of user is so slow and lag. I realize that my code add many events and I think this is the problem. So how can I increase the performance of my code?

Here is my code in background script:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
      function(result) {
             return { cancel: true };
      },
      {
             urls: listUrls,
             types: ["main_frame"]
      },
      ["blocking"]
);
```

And here is listUrls:

```
listUrls = [
    "*://*.abc.com/*",
    "*://*.def.com/*",
    "*://*.afb.com/*",
    "*://*.adf.com/*",
    "*://*.dafg.com/*",
    "*://*.abac.com/*",
    "*://*.dfg.com/*",
    "*://*.asdfa.com/*",
    "*://*.fgfg.com/*",
    // ....
    // More than 500,000 lines
]
```

And when I enable the chrome extension, web browsing experience is so slow and lag. 
Thank you for your viewing and hoping to receive the answer soon.

Comment: There's no solution except using some external proxy software that can filter URLs more efficiently. Or simply via `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can you give me some example or site reference? I am not family with using external proxy software.